# custom attached property not found

Tags: xaml, c++-cx

I want to implement a new property (named "MenuForeground") for the pivot element, in order change the color of the PivotItem header through a defined ControlTemplate.

Therefore I created a new class for the custom property, added the #include in the needed code-behind xaml.h file and defined a new namespace ("xamlns:cap") according to the namespace of the custom property.

PivotProperties.h

```
#pragma once
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
namespace CustomAttachedProperties
{
public ref class PivotProperties sealed : Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject
{
public:
    static Windows::UI::Color GetMenuForeground(UIElement^ obj);
    static void SetMenuForeground(UIElement^ obj, Windows::UI::Color value);

    static property DependencyProperty^ MenuForegroundProperty
    {
        DependencyProperty^ get() { return _menuForegroundProperty; }
    }

    private:
        static DependencyProperty^ _menuForegroundProperty;
    };
}
```

PivotProperties.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "PivotProperties.h"

using namespace CustomAttachedProperties;

DependencyProperty^ PivotProperties::_menuForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty::RegisterAttached(
"MenuForeground",
Windows::UI::Color::typeid,
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Pivot::typeid,
ref new PropertyMetadata(false));

Windows::UI::Color PivotProperties::GetMenuForeground(UIElement^ obj)
{
    return (Windows::UI::Color)obj->GetValue(_menuForegroundProperty);
}

void PivotProperties::SetMenuForeground(UIElement^ obj, Windows::UI::Color value)
{
    obj->SetValue(_menuForegroundProperty, value);
}
```

In order to use the new property for a pivot element I declared a new xml namespace in the root element like the following

```
<Page
    // ...
    xmlns:cap="clr-namespace:CustomAttachedProperties">
```

But if I try to use the new property ...

```
<Pivot x:Name="pivot" cap:PivotProperties.MenuForeground="Red">...</Pivot>
```

... an error pops up, saying: "The attachable property 'MenuForeground' was not found in type 'PivotProperties'.

How to fix that?

Comment: Try "using" instead of "clr-namespace" in your XAML

Comment: still same error, I really don't know why it won't work; in the code-behind xaml.h file I just added #include "PivotProperties.h" after the #pragma once declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter `ownerType` of the [`RegisterAttached`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701833.aspx) method must be

> The owner type that is registering the dependency property

not the type of the object where you want to set the property.

So your declaration should look like this:

```
DependencyProperty^ PivotProperties::_menuForegroundProperty =
    DependencyProperty::RegisterAttached(
        "MenuForeground",
        Windows::UI::Color::typeid,
        PivotProperties::typeid, // here
        ref new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

---

Please note also that it is not necessary that your `PivotProperties` class derives from `DependencyObject`, as long as it only declares attached properties.

You may also consider using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush` as property type to make it conforming with other properties like `Background` and `Foreground`.

Comment: I already tried that too but still not working; if I'm adding "cap:" to the pivot element IntelliSense is making no suggestions for supported property classes, so I guess there's still a problem with include

Comment: well I have to revise my previous posted comment, now it's working after I wrapped it in my projects namespace and using xmln:cap="<project namespace>.<property namespace>"; thx for your help :)